# Tricky Integration And Functions Question

Tags: integration, functions

If there is a functions $f(x)$ such that
$$
f(x) = x+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(x+y)\cdot f(y) \, dy
$$
I tried doing it but it seems to get more and more complex as I proceed.
Find $f(x)$

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a question here.  Also you should say where is problem comes form and your work or at least your thoughts on solving the problem.

Comment: Yeah Sure. So I started by expanding sin(x+y) and then simplifying. Since we are integrating with respect to y the value of that integration will be finite. Thereby taking those as some random constants A and B I tried generating f(x). After that I got two equation in two variables but that too is complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
f(x) = x+\sin(x)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(y)\cdot f(y)+\cos(x)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(y)\cdot f(y) \, dy
$$
Both integrals are constants. Hense:
$$
f(x) = x+c_1\sin(x)+c_2\cos(x)
$$
Then, bring it back into the integral equation :
$$
x+c_1\sin(x)+c_2\cos(x) = x+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(x+y)\cdot \left( y+c_1\sin(y)+c_2\cos(y)\right) \, dy
$$
I let you continue : compute the integral and identify. This will leads to the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ is two-times differentiable..

$$f(x) = x + \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x+y)f(y)dy$$
$$f'(x) = 1 + \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(x+y)f(y)dy$$
$$f''(x) = -\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x+y)f(y)dy$$

$f(x) + f''(x) = x \implies f(x) = c_1 \sin(x) + c_2 \cos(x) + x$

This assumes that we can interchange the derivative and the integral in the calculations of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$. Now you can either try to justify this, or just plug in your original equation the solution found to check that it is indeed a solution

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=1+\int_0^{\pi /2}\cos(x+y)f(y)\,dy$

$f''(x)=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x+y)f(y)\,dy=x-f(x)$.

Then , $f''(x)+f(x)-x=0$

Solve this and you should get a good candidate...